# Deploy requirements for SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I want to use SQLite in a C# application. I was asked to have .NET 3.5 SP1 in my computer.
Do my customers have to have this .NET version installed to run my application?

Comment: What is your reason for choosing sqllite?  If you just want a standalone database file, a better option (better integration with .net) is sql server compact edition (sqlce) which does just that, and is royalty free.

Comment: Not enough information here to be certain.  I don't think SQLite by itself requires .NET, does it?  Your application, on the other hand, if it's a .NET application will require the .NET runtime.  What version depends on what version you're targeting when you compile it.

Comment: I'll have to choose something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the .Net runtime is also required on the client computers.

Comment: Thanks. It was an easy answer for those who know it. I don't understand people that tell you what you have to do instead of answering the question.